# React Native: How does this Component call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Can someone help me with this Component, i want to make like this, but dont know how this white frames called? Can someone tell me this? And if we press that yellow `Touchable Opacity` it is showing whole Text, and if we press again it will became smaller!
Thanks in Advance , I am Just new in RN

[image]

Comment: like you want to know how to display card ?

Comment: i want to know how this card called and to find it in docs of RN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create that card with a little bit of CSS.

Below is the sample app which shows you how you can achieve that.

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/joyous-marshmallows)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { newsFeed } from './news';
export default function App() {
  const [news, setNews] = useState(newsFeed);

  const showFull = (index) => {
    const temp = [...news];
    temp[index].toggle = !temp[index].toggle;
    setNews(temp);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
        data={news}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
              {item.toggle ? item.desc : `${item.desc.substr(0, 100)}...`}
            </Text>
            {item.toggle && (
              <Image source={{ uri: item.img }} style={styles.img} />
            )}
            <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
              <Text style={styles.date}>4/02/2021</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showFull(index)}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <Text style={styles.moreBtn}>
                    {!item.toggle ? 'More' : 'Less'}
                  </Text>
                  <AntDesign
                    name={item.toggle ? 'up' : 'down'}
                    size={12}
                    color="orange"
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomBar: {
    marginVertical: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  card: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  title: {
    marginVertical: 5,

    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  date: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'rgba(21,21,21,0.5)',
  },
  moreBtn: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'orange',
    marginRight: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

actually this card is not a component you can design it using css and if you want to create a component which you can reuse then you can make one component and reuse it as you want and for this card either you can use your own css or a library called native-base which is
like bootstrap but it is used in react-native

you can read about native base here for more information
https://nativebase.io/

and if you want to create card of your own then make a separate file and make a funcional card component in it

and call it wherever you like

```
import myCustomCard from './card'
```

and to use it you use like this in your jsx

```
<myCustomCard />
```

and if you want to know more about how to pass props and else you can checkout official docs of the react native here
https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started